# Why does the result in TOAD and SQLPlus differ?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, toad

I have this query.

```
select
   dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', username) || '/' usercreate
from
   dba_users where username = 'NSAGUN';
```

In TOAD, I get this text. (using SAVE AS TAB DELIMITED)

```
USERCREATE

   CREATE USER "NSAGUN" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '1EE5F58CB716B194'
      DEFAULT TABLESPACE "PIN01"
      TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "PINTEMP"
 /
```

But in SQLPlus I only get this:

```
USERCREATE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE USER "NSAGUN" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '1EE5F58CB716B194'
      DEFAULT T
```

Why is that? And how can I make the output in SQLPlus the same as in TOAD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using these settings in SQL*Plus before executing the query:

```
set long 1000000
set longchunk 1000000
set linesize 200
```

The `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` function returns a CLOB value and by default [SQL*Plus sets the LONG variable to 80 bytes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699121).

Comment: can you explain why these are used? :) thanks @Marco

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> set long 1000000
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL> SELECT
  2     dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', 'LALIT') || '/' usercreate
  3  from
  4     dba_users where username = 'LALIT'
  5  /

   CREATE USER "LALIT" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'S:F10EA8C6778ACE16430E4714FE8C41CFB
2C9E5BC73ADDC503E134EA91AF9;H:076ADC10B6F6540DEEB030DF6C97A752;C6F71E6F6BA0F4BD'

      DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
      TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"/


SQL>
```

**LONG {80|n}**

> ```
> Set the maximum width (in chars) for displaying and copying LONG values.
> ```

**SET PAGES[IZE] {14 | n}**

> Sets the number of rows on each page of output in iSQL*Plus, and the
>   number of lines on each page of output in command-line and Windows
>   GUI. You can set PAGESIZE to zero to suppress all headings, page
>   breaks, titles, the initial blank line, and other formatting
>   information.

Comment: I have made it into script and I want in the logs to produce the same output ( I use spool). But I get a blank space after each line. Can it be formatted in a way that the output in SQLPlus is the same in the log generated by my script?